# insert item to list view flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, insert

i have a list view that contain an image,title for image,description for image and price for it.
i have text fileds for taking this texts and by a bottom i add this image and hole other stuff to list view builder.how can i add just a single item to list view flutter any time press the botton?

```
 Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
         child: ListView.builder(
           scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
           itemCount: list.length,
           itemBuilder:(BuildContext context,int index){
              return new Container(
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0,left: 20.0),
                    child:image[index], 
                    //widget.pic,
                  ),                
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0 ,left: 130.0),    
                child: Text(list[index],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0,fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                fontWeight:FontWeight.bold),)),
                  SizedBox(width: 50.0),
                 Container(width: 60.0,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                   child: SizedBox(width: 150.0,height: 25.0,
                      child: DecoratedBox(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red[700],
                      borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(5.0) ),
                      child: Text(list2[index],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,color: Colors.white),)),                
                   ))]),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right:150.0),
                    child: Text(list3[index],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                  ),                    
                ],),                    
              );
```

Comment: provide the whole code, it would help with giving a solution

Comment: could u give me email or some thing ?

Comment: Sure, here is my email: mhmd.asm.nsr@gmail.com

Comment: did you try this after adding an item to the list rebuild the widgets with `setState(() {});`

Comment: @parisa have you resolved the issue

Comment: @Parisa i would recommend posting the whole code here to make the process of helping you easier.

Comment: @suhaibsalem yes i have tried . when i press save button to icrease the counter item

Comment: @Ggriffo not yet. some of suggested using state managment or provider. im on it